# With JavaScript try/catch, what is clean way to not deal catch error message?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've got a try/catch JavaScript/TypeScript as follows:

```
import ls from 'local-storage';

let user;

try {
  user = ls.get('userInfo');
} catch (e) {
  user = {};
}
```

I have cases where `ls.get()` returns invalid JavaScript which is a fairly normal occurrence and I don't want to report or log the error, I just want to set my user to `{}` as I'm showing above.

That is, ls.get throws an error when local storage is empty and I want to make sure I handle that situation and catch the thrown exception.

Is there a clean or better syntax to do this? If I just say `catch()` I get an error.

Comment: When you say “*invalid javascript*”, what do you mean? Invalid according to the JS interpreter or to your own code? Is it actually returning an object or a JSON string?

Comment: Why is your api returning invalid javascript in the first place? Why do you think this is acceptable? The real solution is to stop your api returning invalid javascript (I'm guessing json)?

Comment: "If I just say catch() I get an error." because you need a code block, even if empty. Use `catch() {}` or `catch(err) {}` (first solution may not be supported yet)

Comment: I updated the question to be include what ls is.  It's not my API (local-storage) and I've found that if local storage gets half updated (like with a blank string instead of valid JSON), ls.get(..) throws an error which I believe I have no choice but to handle through a catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from what was said in the comments, I think you are trying to use something that is not, but will soon be, in the ECMAScript spec (or JS spec) : the [*Optional Catch Binding*](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-catch-binding)

**Until then**, you will get an error if you don't have a parameter (or binding variable) for the error. You can leave the catch code block empty, though :

```
let user;

try {
  user = ls.get('userInfo');
} catch (err) {}
```

Edit: The Optional Catch Binding is supposed to be comming this year (the "Expected Publication Year") according to the [tc39 finished proposal page](https://github.com/tc39/proposals/blob/master/finished-proposals.md)

Comment: Thanks @Seblor  You comment is actually very helpful and more or less validates my concern about having a binding variable included that is never used (code smell).  I'm trying not be offended by people voting down my question :(.  It seems you understood it perfectly.